# An integral equation of a $k$-homogeneous function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, laplacian

Suppose $f$ is a real function over $\mathbb{R}^3$ and satisfies $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ where $k$ is a positive integer and $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$. Let $B(0,1)$ be a unit ball and $\partial B(0,1)$ being its surface. Proove:
$$
\int_{B(0,1)} \Delta f\ dxdydz = k \int_{\partial B(0,1)} f \mu_{\partial B(0,1)}
$$
where $\mu_{\partial B(0,1)}$ is the volume-form over the surface.

I tried 
$$
\int_{B(0,1)} \Delta f\ dxdydz = \int_{B(0,1)} \nabla \cdot \nabla f\ dxdydz = \int_{\partial B(0,1)} \nabla f \cdot \vec{n}\ \mu_{\partial B(0,1)}
$$
But I don't know how to get $\nabla f \cdot \vec{n} = kf$ if possible. As I know, $\vec{n}=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know [Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)?

Comment: @user539887 Oh I see! Thank you!